# os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE') doesn't work

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I'm trying to run a standalone script that uses the Django models for accessing the database.

The script is very simple, see below:

```
import sys
from manager.models import Playlist
from manager.utils import clean_up_playlist, add_record_to_playlist

def main(playlist_id, username):
    playlist = Playlist.objects.get(playlists=playlist_id)
    # the script does other stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    playlist_id = sys.argv[1]
    username = sys.argv[2]
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'SpotifyPlaylistManager.settings')
    import django
    django.setup()
    main(playlist_id, username)
```

The script is in the top folder of the Django folder

```
SpotifyPlaylistManager/
|-SpotifyPlaylistManager/
  |-settings.py
|-venv
|-manage.py
|-my_script.py
```

For some reason, if I try to run it with the command below I got the error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

The actual command I need to launch

```
source /home/nicola/PycharmProjects/SpotifyPlaylistManager/venv/bin/activate && python /home/nicola/PycharmProjects/SpotifyPlaylistManager/scheduler.py 6tIMeXF1Q9bB7KDywBhG2P nicoc && deactivate
```

I can't find the issue

Comment: Can you share the command that through the error? I think you forgot it.

Comment: try moving th import statements to the top of the file so that django is initialised first

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to import the models at the top of your file - you can't do that until Django has been loaded. You need to move the imports to inside the function itself.

Comment: @solarissmoke if you want to add it as an answer as it worked

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Django include inside the main worked

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    playlist_id = sys.argv[1]
    username = sys.argv[2]
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'SpotifyPlaylistManager.settings')
    import django
    django.setup()
    from manager.models import Playlist
    from manager.utils import clean_up_playlist, add_record_to_playlist

    main(playlist_id, username)
```